# Current month first and last day is wrong

Tags: javascript, date

I need to fetch the first and last day of the current month. I created the solution using the core JS new Date() method.

```
const date = new Date();
const firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
const lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

console.log(firstDay.toUTCString(), lastDay.toUTCString()); //Tue, 31 Mar 2020 18:30:00 GMT Wed, 29 Apr 2020 18:30:00 GMT
```

When I try a similar thing in the browser's console, it prints the result as expected, i.e. `1st April 2020 and 30th April 2020`, but testing it in the postman environment, gives the wrong result.

Can anyone please help to resolve this confusion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code:

```js
var d = new Date(),
  e = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1),
  f = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0);
  
console.log(e.toUTCString() + "\n" + f.toUTCString());
```

so you get wrong result because you want to get the UTC string
from local date, you need to make it UTC date in order to print
UTC string correctly.

```js
var d = new Date(),
  e = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), 1)),
  f = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0));
  
console.log(e.toUTCString() + "\n" + f.toUTCString());
```

Comment: Adding UTC worked. Can you please elaborate on this?